# Change of variable for a integration of compactly supported continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

The following question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing  and I was unable to think whether following option is true or not?

> Let t and a be positive real numbers . Define $B_a$ ={x= $(x_1 , x_2 , ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n $ | $ {x_1}^2 +...+{x_n}^2 \leq a^2$}. Then for any compactly supported continuous function f:

How I can prove that $ \int_{ B_a}   {f(xt) dx} =\int_{B_{ta}}   {f(x) t^{-n} dx}$?

For 1 variable I have done it but for n variables how can I do it ?  Which Concept should I use?

Kind regards!

Comment: you could use the fact that every compactly supported continuous function is integrable and then use fubini in order to perform variable change to each coordinate separately. or, preferably, you could directly do variable change and use the jacobian. or you could do it for characteristic functions and then by density show it for every $L^p$ and thus for $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The last approach requires of course measure theory

Comment: Do you know the change of variable theorem for multivariable?